# ROS Answers SE migration: hector slam

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i start my hykou node and then start any of the hector slam launch file i get the following error  on the laser scan node i get that there is no fixed frame in it any help please ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45919/hector-slam/) by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like you haven't set up your tf tree correctly. Have a look at the [answer here](http://answers.ros.org/question/40414/setting-up-tf-for-hector-slam/).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0